# Cannot longer deploy my firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I have a lot of error when trying to reply my fibres functions.

Looks like it is related to `lint`.

```
$ npm run deploy

> deploy
> firebase deploy --only functions


=== Deploying to 'sXXXXe-XXX'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/stephanedeluca/development/XX/XX/functions
> eslint .


/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions/dist/index.dev.js
     7:497  error  Unsafe usage of ThrowStatement                                   no-unsafe-finally
    73:10   error  'regeneratorRuntime' is not defined                              no-undef
    74:12   error  Unexpected constant condition                                    no-constant-condition
```

The logs:

```
functions$ cat   /Users/stephanedeluca/.npm/_logs/2023-11-30T21_18_47_713Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/firebase',
1 verbose cli   '/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli',
1 verbose cli   '--script-shell=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell',
1 verbose cli   '--globalconfig=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--userconfig=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v16.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prelint: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~lint: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: PATH: /snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions/node_modules/.bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions/node_modules/.bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/node_modules/.bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/node_modules/.bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/node_modules/.bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/node_modules/.bin:/Users/node_modules/.bin:/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/node-gyp-bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/flutter/bin/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/opt/postgresql@11/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/stephanedeluca/development/flutter/bin/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/opt/postgresql@11/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/bin:~/development/flutter/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.pub-cache/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.rvm/bin:~/development/flutter/bin:/Users/stephanedeluca/.pub-cache/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: CWD: /Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'eslint .' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ lint: `eslint .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X
16 verbose Darwin 23.1.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/firebase" "/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli" "--script-shell=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell" "--globalconfig=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" "--userconfig=/Users/stephanedeluca/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto" "--prefix" "/Users/stephanedeluca/development/X/X/functions" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v16.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ lint: `eslint .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You have three different, unrelated eslint errors in the output.  They each have the word "error" in them. You should do a web search for each one to understand and correct each problem separately.  If you don't want to fix them, then you should disable eslint entirely, or disable them each separately.  Basically, you will have to learn something about how eslint works and why it's giving you errors on code that would normally compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a fix.

For some reasons, removing my `dist` folder is the solution.

And running `npm run deploy` again is now OK.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the default configuration of a Firebase Functions project which will run `lint`, and your code is failing the `lint` rules leading to the deploy failing.

Either fix your code's issues as described in the lint error output, or disable linting as part of the deployment process.  See the `scripts` section of `package.json` in your "functions" project.

I would recommend that you fix the linting errors, but in case you cannot do so right now, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408143/how-do-i-resolve-new-eslint-errors-in-my-cloud-functions-project#:%7E:text=If%20you%20simply%20cannot%20use,that%20runs%20the%20lint%20command.).